# sql server user authentication not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

i created a software in vb.net 2005.  i create a database in sql server 2005. i connect it with window authentication. everything works fine.

but problem started when i replace my database with old database copyed from different computer.

i attach screnshot of both database with attached users.

old database 
[image]

and new database is

[image]

when i try to connect my software with old database with window authentication, it is not connected.

can anyone please tell me what the problem is and how to solve this?

Comment: Cannot open database "tara" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Gautam-PC\Gautam'.

Comment: Can you check if the username in the database is mapped to a login? Open the user and in General tab, check if the login is there.

Answer (score 2):

When you restore a Microsoft SQL Server database on a different machine, the user could be no more the same on the previous machine. Even if you see the same username listed.

This user is called an ['orphaned user'.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx)

Meaning that there is no login id or password associated with the user since the original SID identifying the user is no more valid on the new machine.

You could check if you have this situation with

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'
```

and, you could fix with

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'Gauntam-PC\Gautam'
```

Comment: The number of orphaned users fixed by updating users was 0.
The number of orphaned users fixed by adding new logins and then updating users was 0.

Comment: On which database are you executing the commands? 'tara' or 'taranew'?

Comment: on tara, its old database